# OpenCV: Failed to read image from pipe

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I'm trying to load the image from pipe such as stdin, named pipe, etc.

This is my sample code:

> #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
>
> using namespace cv;
>
> int main(int argc, char **argv) {
>
> ```
>    Mat img;
>    if(argc > 1) img = imread(argv[1]);
>    else img = imread("/dev/stdin");
>    printf("rows = %d, cols = %d\n", img.rows, img.cols);
>    imshow("original", img);
>    while (waitKey(1) != 'q');
>    return 0;
> ```
>
> }

```
./a.out image.jpg
```

will work, but

```
./a.out < image.jpg
```

and

```
mkfifo img.pipe
./a.out img.pipe
cat image.jpg > img.pipe
```

won't work and rows and cols of Mat img are 0.

What's the difference between real file and pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `imread` is to read image from block device, instead of stream device. the local file is of block, and pipe is of stream, that's why the function `imread` can not read image from pipes, sockets, etc.

Comment: Thank you raison! So, it means that `imread` uses some features such as  random-access-file, which supported by block devices but not stream devices?